# Want to use HLOOKUP to drag down the whole column, how can I do this?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

See the following screenshot:

[image]

This is only an example, my real worksheet is more complicated than this and has hundreds of rows.

My current formula is `=HLOOKUP(A7,A1:D4,2,0)`, but this formula doesn't allow me to drag it down the column so that I can get "2-Jan-12" and "3-Jan-12" for Tom too. How can I change the formula to make it suitable for dragging down?

---

Update: I tried `=HLOOKUP($A$7,$A$1:$D$4,2,0)`, but upon dragging down now I get 5 for "2-Jan-12" and "3-Jan-12" as well. I want to drag the formula down so that "2-Jan-12" shows 6 and "3-Jan-12" shows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the 2 also so you can use this version in B8 copied down

`=HLOOKUP(A$7,$A$1:$D$4,ROWS(B$8:B8)+1,0)`

`ROWS` function increments as you drag down and changes the `row_index_num` in `HLOOKUP` to 3, 4 etc.

Note: the above doesn't actually match the dates, it just gets the value from the next row regardless of date, to specifically match dates use this version

`=INDEX(B$2:D$4,MATCH(A8,A$2:A$4,0),MATCH(A$7,B$1:D$1,0))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure whehter this is what you're looking for, but to make single columns or rows not change upon dragging, add a `$` in front of them:

- `A1` will always update based on the direction you drag the cell.
- `$A1` will only update the row when dragging up/down.
- `A$1` will only update the column when dragging left/right.
- `$A$1` will never change no matter how/where you drag the cell.

---

For the updated question:

I tested the following formula for the cell `B8`:

```
=HLOOKUP($A$7,$B$1:$D$4,MATCH($A8,$A$1:$A$4,0),0)
```

The `MATCH` will determine the n-th row as determined by the date in the first column, which then will pick the correct row from the first table using `HLOOKUP`.

Comment: i updated the question giving more details, could u pls have a look?

Comment: Added the solution I used - give it a try (works fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with this.  Here's the formula I used:

[image: Hlookup]

```
=HLOOKUP($B$1,$C$1:$E$4,ROW(),FALSE)
```

`HLOOKUP` looks across your columns and returns the first value $B$1 (using $ to keep the absolute reference).  The lookup range also uses absolute values so it doesn't "creep" as you drag and fill the formula.  The `ROW` function returns the values in the same row without having to do any extra calculations.  I also used data validation to populate the lookup value in $B$1 with one of your existing lookup values, giving you a quick drop down to work with.  By keeping the "target" value in the same data layout (rows & columns) as your source data, it makes everything simpler to manage (as opposed to your example where it's offset by a number of rows).  Good data layout makes almost everything easier in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

You need to "fix" the references for the array: `=HLOOKUP(A7,$A$1:$D$4,2,0)`

Comment: i tried that, but dragging the formula down gives #N/A